# PictureBox Runtime Image

Tags: .net, runtime, image-manipulation, picturebox, image-resizing

To see the problems, please follow these steps (I am coding in C#):

1. Put a picturebox on a form named picturebox1
2. Resize it to small rectangle (say 75,75)
3. Add a picture to resources (named say pic) larger than that rectangle (say 500,500)

Now we are ready :D

I know two ways to have this picture shown in the picturebox at runtime while showing the whole picture not only a part of it:

1. Adding Imagelist and setting size (this is not good at all)
2. Writing onPaint of that picturebox something like this:

> e.Graphics.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.pic,
>   new Rectangle(0,0,75,75));

Lets assume that I want to fill the Image property of the picturebox1, now I must write something like this:

> pictureBox1.Image = (Image)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("pic1");

which does not resize the image retrieved. I want to know if there is a good way around this problem (to resize and assign easily)? BTW, I don't want to resize the picture using something like these

1. [Image Editing Using C#](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBMQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.switchonthecode.com%2Ftutorials%2Fcsharp-tutorial-image-editing-saving-cropping-and-resizing&ei=77FsTe-AOdCUswaPk_W1BQ&usg=AFQjCNFUWSE3JC-UrqF6pUwaPmm9XMy6bQ)
2. [Image Editing while maintaining aspect ratio](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CBoQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsnippets.dzone.com%2Fposts%2Fshow%2F4336&ei=77FsTe-AOdCUswaPk_W1BQ&usg=AFQjCNGW6Xs9uEQSJNnD__W-Mf7ntAWc5g)

Now the second question:

I know resources are statically added in my example, but is there a way to get the name of the resource programmatically instead of hardcoding it as string and passing it to the "GetObject()" method?

Comment: I forgot to tell that there is a way to assign image (but still static) by Properties.Resources.pic1. I don't want it cause it is static and does not give me the name of the resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default PictureBox doesn't size the image to fit with its display area. Try this:

```
pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
```